# Access: Combining multiple rows into one, but show text

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to form a single row from multiple rows by using GROUP BY in my SQL statement.

Problem is, the raw data I am working with contains data that I do not need, and all the fields are populated with text strings.

For example,

```
ID COURSE
01 Baking 101
01 Driving 102
01 Writing 101
02 Baking 102
02 Writing 101
```

I don't need 'Writing', only 'Baking' and 'Driving'. So I'd like my data to turn up like this:

```
ID Baking     Driving
01 Baking 101 Driving 102
02 Baking 102 -
```

I am selecting records by seeing if they contain the relevant keywords, because my raw data source contains the course history of all courses, not just the ones that I am concerned with. And the spelling of the courses can vary for the same course.

As of now, I am using a IIf statement to return a 1 if the keyword is present and a 0 if the keyword isn't. I then Sum it and GROUP BY my ID (Personal identifier). So my table turns out a bit like this.

```
ID Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
01    1       0       0       1       0
02    0       1       1       0       0
```

What I would like is for my query to display the record IF the record contains a certain keyword, while still grouping and truncating all related records into a single row.

A GROUP BY function can't do that (afaik) because it doesn't know how to handle text strings (i.e. it doesn't know which record to display), which is why I am using an IIf to generate a number then Sum to allow GROUP BY. Is there a way for me to perhaps convert the number back into the text (i.e. the text that satisfies my IIf statement)

I apologise for not being able to provide an actual sample of the data, but it's corporate data that I can't share unfortunately.

Edit:

What I mean when I say the spelling varies is something like this:

```
1.Baking 101 Cse
2.Baking 101 Course
3.Baking-101 Cse
```

So as of now, my SELECT statement is something like this

```
SELECT Courses.CourseName,
Sumiif((Courses.CourseName Like "*Baking*",1,0) AS BAKING
FROM Courses
GROUP BY Courses.PersID
```

This is quite a bit simplified, because I have more than 1 course to handle.

So the problem I am facing is that I want to display the actual data in the field, and not the result of my IIf function. i.e. instead of a 1, I want to see the name of the course. However, I also need to group by my primary key, which requires that I use an aggregate function. I am not aware of an aggregate function that can do this with strings.

Comment: Can you post your query and the results you 'really' want to show, even if its dummy data. This would help us further understand what you want.

Comment: In your current question, there's no way to see a relationship between _Baking 101_ and _Baking 102_, so there's no way to know these belong in the same column. If you have a table with all column names, and the values belonging in that column, you can solve this easily with a pivot. In it's current state, you can't solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'spelling can vary' - just the number suffix changes? The course name and section really should be in separate fields. However, use string manipulation functions to parse the parts in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a table or query like:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+
| CourseID | CourseName | CourseSection |
+----------+------------+---------------+
|       01 | Baking     |           101 |
|       01 | Driving    |           102 |
|       01 | Writing    |           101 |
|       02 | Baking     |           102 |
|       02 | Writing    |           101 |
+----------+------------+---------------+
```

And query:

```
TRANSFORM First(Courses.CourseSection) AS FirstOfCourseSection
SELECT Courses.CourseID
FROM Courses
WHERE (((Courses.CourseName)<>"Writing"))
GROUP BY Courses.CourseID
PIVOT Courses.CourseName;
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| CourseID | Baking | Driving |
+----------+--------+---------+
|       01 |    101 |     102 |
|       02 |    102 |         |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

If your course names are less consistent for spelling and the name and section are actually in one field but the section suffix is consistent, then emulate a crosstab like:

```
SELECT Courses.CourseID, Max(IIf(InStr([CourseName],"Baking")>0,Right([CourseName],3),Null)) AS Baking, 
Max(IIf(InStr([CourseName],"Driving")>0,Right([CourseName],3),Null)) AS Driving
FROM Courses
GROUP BY Courses.CourseID;
```